# Is it ok to use a delta table tracker based on parquet file name in Azure databricks?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, delta-lake

Today at work i saw a **delta lake** tracker based on file name. By delta tracker, i mean a function that defines whether a parquet file has already been ingested or not.

The code would check what file (from the delta table) has **not** already been ingested, and the parquets file in the delta table would then be read using this : `spark.createDataFrame(path,StringType())`

Having worked with **Delta tables**, it does not seem ok to me to use a **delta tracker** that way.

- In case record is **deleted**, what are the chances that the `delta log` would point to a new file , and *that this deleted record would
  be read as a new one?*
- In case record is **updated**, what would be the chance that `delta log` would not point to a new file, and *that this updated record
  would not be considered ?*
- In case some **maintenance** is happening on the delta table, *what are
  the chances that some new files are written out of nowhere ?* Which may cause a record to be re-ingested

Any observation or suggestion whether it is ok to work that way would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Delta Lake everything works on file level. So there are no 'in place' updates or deletes. Say a single record gets deleted (or updated) then roughly the following happens:

1. Read in the parquet file with the relevant record (+ the other records which happen to be in the file)
2. Write out all records except for the deleted record into a new parquet file
3. Update the transaction log with a new version, marking the old parquet file as removed and the new parquet file as added. Note the old parquet file doesn't get physically deleted until you run the [`VACUUM`](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-vacuum.html) command.

The process for an update is basically the same.

To answer your questions more specifically:

> In case record is deleted, what are the chances that the delta log
> would point to a new file , and that this deleted record would be read
> as a new one?

The delta log will point to a new file, but the deleted record will not be in there. There will be all the other records which happened to be in the original file.

> In case record is updated, what would be the chance that delta log
> would not point to a new file, and that this updated record would not
> be considered ?

Files are not updated in place, so this doesn't happen. A new file is written containing the updated record (+ any other other records in the original file). The transaction log is updated to 'point' to this new file.

> In case some maintenance is happening on the delta table, what are the
> chances that some new files are written out of nowhere ? Which may
> cause a record to be re-ingested

This is possible, although not 'out of nowhere'. For example if you run [`OPTIMIZE`](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-optimize.html) existing parquet files get reshuffled/combined to improve performance. Basically this means a number of new parquet files will be written and a new version in the transaction log will point to these parquet files. If you pickup all new files after this you will re-ingest data.

Some considerations: if your delta table is append only you could use [structured streaming](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-streaming.html) to read from it instead. If not then Databricks offers [Change Data Feed](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-change-data-feed.html) giving your record level details of inserts, updates and deletes.